# What is the purpose of the "constructor header" in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

This page here: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/rts/storage/heap-objects suggests that every object in GHC has a header.

So lets say I have:

```
data X = X1 Int# | X2 Int# Int#
```

My understanding is that adding `X` to a data type effectively takes three words in the case of `X1`, and four words in the case of `X2` (assuming it's evaluated). One for the pointer to either `X1` or `X2` (which will be tagged with what it is), the header of `X1` or `X2`, and then one or two words.

What is the purpose of the header? It's my understanding that Haskell erases all types at runtime and doesn't do runtime reflection (unless one opts into things like `Typeable`).

If a function is polymorphic, say `f :: a -> a`, then `f` can't actually do anything with `a` other than copy it around. It can't actually inspect `a`, so if it needs to copy it around it should just be able to copy the pointer to it.

Now if we've got `g :: Num a => a -> a`, then we've got a type class dictionary that knows, at compile time, the layout of `a`. For example, if we do `g (42 :: Int)`, then we know at compile time to make a `Num Int` dictionary and pass it to `g` along with `42 :: Int`. That `Num Int` dictionary knows the layout of `Int`, so again, it won't need to inspect it's header for that information at runtime.

So what is the purpose of the constructor header? How is it used and in what circumstances is it necessary and actually inspected by real code at runtime?

*Edit*

@chi and @William below has pointed out that if a type has multiple constructors, then a header will be required to differentiate them at runtime. This is a fair point, but then poses the questions:

1. If a type has only one constructor, then surely the header isn't needed.
2. If a type has no more than 7 constructors (or no more than 3 on a 32 bit system) then shouldn't pointer tagging handle this case? In the case where the data is an unevaluated thunk, well, we don't know what constructor it is yet anyway so we don't need a header, and when it's evaluated we can point to it with a tagged pointer, again not needing the header.

Comment: It erases all *type* information, but `X1` is not type information, that is *data* information. It specifies which of the two constructors was used. But both objects have the same type.

Comment: Did you read that page?  It discusses a bunch of information that gets stored in the header, including information that the GC needs even in erased types, whether or not the value is a WHNF value or an unevaluated thunk, all things that are needed even for the objects you describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the key points have been covered in the comments, but the GHC runtime uses constructor headers to support both lazy evaluation (without duplicate evaluation of shared objects) and to support garbage collection.

The lazy evaluation is the harder one to understand, so let's start with that...

Say we have:

```
data X = X1 Int# | X2 Int# Int#
```

and suppose we have a function:

```
foo :: X -> Int
foo (X1 a) = I# a
foo (X2 a b) = I# (a #+ b)
```

The code for `foo` needs to handle tagged pointers for objects already evaluated to WHNF, but it also needs to handle thunks.  The way GHC handles thunks is by laying them out in memory as:

```
x_closure:
    .quad    x_info   ; pointer to code to evaluate the thunk
    .quad    ...      ; additional payload, if any, for the code at x_info
```

and generating code for `foo` something like:

```
foo(x_ptr):=
    if (*x_ptr & 7) == 0 then x_ptr := (*x_ptr)(x_ptr)
    if (*x_ptr & 7 == 1) then ...handle X1...
    elif (*x_ptr & 7 == 2) then ...handle X2...
```

Here, `x_ptr := (*x_ptr)(x_ptr)` runs the code pointed to by the first word of the thunk object (`x_info`, in the example above), passing it the pointer as an input argument and updating the pointer based on the returned result.  The argument and result conventions are less important than the key fact that, to evaluate a thunk, GHC calls code at the address given by the first word of the thunk.

Now, this `foo` works fine for fully evaluated `X` objects, regardless of whether or not they are laid out with a constructor header:

```
; actual layout used by GHC
x1_closure:
    .quad   X1_con_info
    .quad   42
```

or without:

```
; optimized layout proposed by @Clinton
x1_closure:
    .quad   42
```

*provided* that all pointers are always properly tagged.

The problem is the one already pointed out by @chi in a comment.  If we have an object that started life as a untagged pointer to a thunk, when it eventually gets evaluated and the pointer is "upgraded" to a tagged pointer, there may be many copies of the original untagged pointer floating around in various objects.  To avoid evaluating thunks multiple times, GHC evaluates the thunk *in place*, so all those untagged pointers are pointing at the right block of memory, but they are still untagged, so if someone calls `foo` on such a pointer, it will try to jump to the first word of the "thunk", which is a disaster if the object has been upgraded in place with an optimized layout:

```
; optimized layout
x1_closure:
    .quad   42
```

On the other hand, it all works seamlessly if the GHC layout is used:

```
; actual layout used by GHC
x1_closure:
    .quad   X1_con_info
    .quad   42
```

and the code blocks associated with `X1_con_info` and `X2_con_info` just temporarily add the tag to the untagged pointer:

```
X1_con_info(x_ptr) :=
    return(x_ptr+1)

X2_con_info(x_ptr) :=
    return(x_ptr+2)
```

to allow `foo` to run successfully.  Note that this *doesn't* actually tag the *source* copy of this untagged pointer, but the garbage collector can do that later -- for each untagged pointer it encounters while traversing objects in memory, it can check the header pointer (e.g., `X1_con_info`) and check the associated info block, which will show whether or not that header pointer references a constructor, and -- if so -- its appropriate tag.

Now, if you look very carefully at what I just described, you'll see that it would be possible to identify objects that started life in WHNF and have never been referenced by an untagged pointer.  If you arranged for all the pointers to point at the payload, with the header coming the word before the payload, I guess you could optimize away headers for this subset of objects, secure in the knowledge that there are no untagged pointers anywhere that could result in an attempt to jump to a non-existent header address.

That would work, I think, but in realistic Haskell code, there aren't many objects that start life in WHNF, so it wouldn't be much of a savings.  Also, it would cause problems with garbage collection...

Which brings us to... erm... garbage collection.  Sure "types are erased", but not as far as the garbage collector is concerned.  It needs to traverse objects without knowledge of the types involved, identifying which fields are pointers and which are, say, unboxed integers.  This is easy if every object starts with a header:

```
; actual layout used by GHC
x1_closure:
    .quad   X1_con_info
    .quad   42
```

since the GC can consult the block of memory just before the code at `X1_con_info` (i.e., the actual info block) to get a total field count and identification of pointers and non-pointers.

Without these headers, the only way to accomplish garbage collection would be to actually generate a custom garbage collector with erased types, basically a recursive collection of garbage collection "functions", one function for every type in the application.

Answer (score 3):

Consider

```
f :: X -> Int#
f (X1 x)   = x
f (X2 _ y) = y
```

`f` needs to know what's the constructor inside its input so to take the first word or the second one.

To stress the point, you can also consider `data Bool = False | True`. Here the constructor name *is* the value, so we need to represent it somehow.

Comment: The pointer to `X1` or `X2` is tagged: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/rts/haskell-execution/pointer-tagging 

The tag will reveal the constructor. There's still no need for the header unless there's more than 7 (or 3 on 32 bit systems) constructors. And the number of constructors is known at compile time. So we can avoid the header for all constructors on 64 bit systems which are part of types which have no more than seven constructors.

Or have I got something wrong here?

Comment: @Clinton Good point. I'll make a guess about why the header still matters. According to the link you provided, the pointer tag can be `0` if the value is an unevaluated thunk. Consider the definition `y = let x = not True in (x,x)`. Inside the pair there are two pointers to the thunk `not True`, having tag 0. After we force `fst y` we can change the tag of the first pointer to reflect the constructor `False` in the result. However, the second pointer in the pair will still have tag 0. If we access that, we need to recover the `False` from the pointed-to data (without recomputing `x`).

Comment: @Clinton Mine is only a guess, but note that in my example `not` might be expensive to compute, so we don't want to evaluate it twice. It looks like if multiple pointers point to the same value, some of them might have a zero tag (for thunks), while others have the constructor tag. Hence I think we still need the constructor header. If we knew there's only one pointer around then I guess an optimization could be performed skipping the header.